# Android, accessing resource files from a native/NDK shared library

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, android-source

I am working on creating a native shared library for an older android API level. I am able to invoke functions in the library from client code.

But I need to use some image files in the shared library. The reference 1 && 3 mentioned a way to access resource files by using java code. My question is: is there a way allowing me to use (something like fopen(res_path)) c/c++ function to open resource files?

The library source structure is:

```
.
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── Android.mk
├── Application.mk
├── res
│   └── drawable
│       ├── 0.jpg
│       ├── 1.jpg
│       ├── ...
│       └── 9.jpg
├── MyApp.cpp
└── MyApp.h
```

Thanks in advance

---

**environment:**

ndk ver : ndk-r12b
compiler: gcc c/c++ 4.9.x
AOSP    : 5.1.1_r30
API level: 22

**references:**

1. [how to access resources in a android library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053141/how-to-access-resources-in-a-android-library-project)
2. [providing resource on android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)
3. [Accessing resources on android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)

Comment: I usually use a raw folder in the res folder, to store the images in the apk internal storage. But you need to add some functions in java to store your files. If I have time I will post an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25560443/3968164), the NDK provides an API to access the **assets** folder (`AAssetManager`, see [here](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/#assets)).

Alternatively, an easy way that I used in one of my projects is to write the necessary files to the filesystem (e.g. /storage or /sdcard) on the Java side and then only pass the filepath to the NDK.

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346889/how-to-reference-an-asset-in-a-library-project) a shared library is not able to access assets

Comment: The last edit of the referenced answer states that with the Gradle Build System, you should be able to access assets in a library. Did you try to use the AAssetManager?

Comment: Since I am not using the Android Studio, Gradle build system seems not a good option for me.